# Why is data in JSON file didn't change, but in runtime I can see new data

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have a JSON file in the project and I want to change some data in it. I wrote code it changed data in runtime but the JSON file in the project stayed without any changes. Please help me find the problem.

This is code in Programm.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using WorkWithJson.Model;

namespace WorkWithJson
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileLocation = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data", "TestData.json");

            var oldData = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);           

            var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new ExpandoObjectConverter());
            jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

            dynamic newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonModel>>(oldData, jsonSettings);

            newData[0].Name = "Pipiter";

            var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newData, Formatting.Indented, jsonSettings);

            File.WriteAllText(fileLocation, newJson);
        }
    }
}
```

This is o model for JSON data

```
namespace WorkWithJson.Model
{
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is JSON which I want change

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pavel",
    "surname": "Pypkin",
    "age": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Fedot",
    "surname": "Ikot",
    "age": 900
  }
]
```

This is csproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Data\TestData.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This is output in runtime, but the TestData.json file stayed without any changes

[Runtime output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtl2z.png)

Comment: Check `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. Is it the expected value (otherwise you're changing a different file).

Comment: @PavelPanasiuk How do you know that it is without any cnanges?

Comment: @Poul Bak Thaks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be 2 conditions you are facing.

1. You are running this program in IDE, the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` maybe not the `bin` dir. You can print the full path and findout which file you are actually writing.

```
Console.WriteLine(fileLocation);
```

2. You may have some software openning the json file which has been locked. It must be some exception when `File.WriteAllText`. If no exception thrown, not this issue.

Comment: You were absolutely right that I changed the file in the bin directory. When I specified the exact path to the file I needed, everything turned out. `var fileLocation = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\pavel\source\repos\WorkWithJson\WorkWithJson\Data\TestData.json");`